# Map a reversed object with Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I found nothing about this, I tried to reverse an object with Mapstruct I don't know if it's even possible or if I have to write a specific method

My objets are like this:

```
public class A {
    private String name;
    private AChild child;
}
public class AChild {
    private String name;
    private AChild child;
}

public class B {
    private String name;
    private BParent parent;
}
public class BParent {
    private String name;
    private BParent parent;
}
```

we would have an A like this :

```
A : {
    name: "grandpa",
    child: {
        name: "dad",
        child: {
            name: "me",
        }
    }
}
```

and we would like this B:

```
B: {
    name: "me",
    parent: {
        name: "dad",
        parent: {
            name: "grandpa"
        }
    }
}
```

we could possibly have an infinite recursion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flipping the tree order doesn't seem to have an obvious solution in MapStruct.  One option is to use MapStruct for the straightforward mapping pieces ("name" in this case), and use a custom mapping method for swapping the ordering:

```java
@Mapper
public interface AToBMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "parent", ignore = true)
    BParent parentNameOnly(A a);

    @Mapping(target = "parent", ignore = true)
    BParent parentNameOnly(AChild a);

    B parentToB(BParent b);

    default B aToB(A a) {
        List<BParent> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(parentNameOnly(a));
        for (AChild child = a.child; child != null; child = child.child) {
            list.add(parentNameOnly(child));
        }
        Collections.reverse(list);
        BParent current = list.get(0);
        for (BParent next : list.subList(1, list.size())) {
            current.parent = next;
            current = next;
        }
        return parentToB(list.get(0));
    }
}
```

```java
// Assuming A & AChild each have a (String name, AChild child) constructor

A a = new A("grandpa", new AChild("dad", new AChild("me", null)));
B b = Mappers.getMapper(AToBMapper.class).aToB(a);
```